# Drag & Drop attachment to Thunderbird's icon in Unity?

Tags: unity, thunderbird

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity 3D and Thunderbird 9.0. When I have a composing window for an email I'd like to attach a file using drag&drop via TB's icon on Unity.

With past Ubuntu 11.04 it was possible, but not now. May I have again this possibility?

Answer (score 1):

You should likely file a bug.

If wanting to add attachments to TB via DnD then the mimetype of what you're attaching needs to be in TB's .desktop on the MimeType= line.

So for text attachments then this would need to be there or added to end of the line

```
text/plain;
```

To try - open the .desktop & edit the MimeType= line

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/thunderbird.desktop
```

Note that this will open a new compose window w/ the file attached so would need to be the 1st action to be useful, ie. DnD the attachment, then compose the message, ect.

Answer (score 0):

When something that used to work, no longer works, it is called a regression. Particularly if it isn't obvious why the feature was removed, you should file a bug so that the developers are made aware of it. This site is not suitable for bug reports. Instead, we use http://Launchpad.net for that. If you need help filing a bug, look for answers here, and if you can't find any, ask a new question. :)